# C# Advanced form "please wait"

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

My form is going to run some code that might take a while to execute. I would like to display a "please wait" message while the operation is running on the background.

I'd like to have that message in a form, one that I can control its visibility, and also its text, from other forms.

I'd also like it to be set to start in the Program.cs file.

My code, so far:

```
namespace KAN
{
    public partial class prosze_czekac : Form
    {
        public prosze_czekac()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private delegate void OffVisible();
        public void Wylacz()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new OffVisible(Wylacz));
            else
                this.Visible = false;
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        public void ZmienTekst(string text)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                //SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(this.ZmienTekst);
                Invoke(new SetTextCallback(this.ZmienTekst), text);
                //Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.Visible = true;
                this.Text = text;
                this.lblKomunikat.Text = text;
                this.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know how to run a form, how to create an instance and as editing text. All this in any form, any thread.
Is the above code is correct and how to use it to make it properly?

How am I so ready form "please wait" I would like to turn it on now in the initial class (Program.cs). Use it in any form design.
Sample code, do not know if correct:

```
namespace KAN
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static prosze_czekac PleaseWait;

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>        
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PleaseWait.Show());

            PleaseWait.ZmienTekst("Please wait... Running the program");

            // long operation

            PleaseWait.Wylacz();

            Application.Run(new main());
        }

    }
}

namespace KAN
{
    public partial class main: Form
    {
        public main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // examples of long task in another form
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Program.PleaseWait.ZmienTekst((i + 1).ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Program.PleaseWait.Wylacz();
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I ask a question, please bear with me.

PS
"Wylacz" is "exit" (void) and is meant to "hide" so that every time you do not initiate the form.
"prosze_czekac" is "please wait".

Comment: Dolbra Jean Acronis :)

Comment: Ok, you have stated yout intent, and shown us the code for what you've tried so far. Thumbs up for that. But how is the code above not working out for you? Is it incomplete? Is it giving you an error? I think I speak for everyone here wen I say we wouldn't copy/paste that into an IDE just to look for a bug which might not even be there.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, *prosze_czekac* makes me think you're into selling *prozac* online.

Comment: I do not know how to run a form, how to create an instance and as editing text. All this in any form, any thread.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include your doubts there. As it is now this question is halfway to being closed by votes, and few people will read the comments to see your question finer details.

Comment: @Renan *Prosze czekac* means *please wait*.

Comment: @Renan
okey, okey. edited

Comment: @Acronis though this question has been put on hold, I have voted to reopen it. It'll still take a few more votes to get it open again, though. Just a friendly hint, from someone who's had questions closed in the Stack Exchange sites too: next time read your own question as though you were someone who knows nothing about your problem. See if an outsider would understand it the way it is asked.

Comment: @Renan Thank you. I append a few more sentences to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Renan Is now the right? :)

Comment: @Acronis It got reopened, so you are on the right track. I hope you get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the BackgroundWorker. The following code assumes, you have a button 'button1' in your form, which executes the worker, which starts the long running task on a different thread:

```
BackgroundWorker _worker;

// button click starts the execution of the lung running task on another thread
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = true; // show the label "please wait"
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // initialize worker
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

// executes when long running task has finished
void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // hide the label
    label1.Visible = false;
}

// is called by 'RunWorkerAsync' and executes the long running task on a different thread
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // long running task (just an example)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
    }
}
```